# Libgdx: Multiplexer does not continue to inputProcessor returns true?

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been searching but can't seem to find the solution. I'm trying to implement a game where the player will press a button to create a new object/body. This object is suppose to be handled with a mousejoint and I want it object and mousejoint to depend if my mouse in pressed down or not. And the creation of the object should depend on of the button is pressed.

I create my input processor like this:

`InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(uiStage, this);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);`

Then for the TextButton I add an InputListener.

```
    button.addListener(new InputListener() {

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float coordX, float coordY, int pointer, int button) {
            createPlank = true;
            System.out.println("button touchDown");
            return false;   
        }
    });
```

As I return false in the touchDown I think that the InputHandler (this) should be called. The problem is that it doesn't seam to get there. It is as if I would return true. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? What might be the problem that the next Inputprocessor does not get to handle the touch?